# How does constructor dependency injection work?

Tags: dependency-injection

I recently had a question from a colleague about how dependency injection works. The article below explains it clearly.

https://blogs.endjin.com/2014/04/understanding-dependency-injection/

However, I have a specific question that I still can't answer because I don't understand: How does a constructor, not called using using methods like .Resolve or .GetInstance get created? Does the DI framework somehow intercept them and supply the required constructor dependencies?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Did you mean "How does a constructor get called using using methods like .Resolve or .GetInstance get created?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It usually uses reflection to investigate constructor signature and pass appropriate parameters. Actual creation can be accomplished using `Activator.CreateInstance` (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wcxyzt4d(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost it is important to understand that DI *doet not* require the use of a DI library a.k.a. DI Container. DI is a set of principles and practices and a DI Container is an optional tool. Applying DI *without* a Container is a practice called [Pure DI](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di/). [This article](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/11/06/WhentouseaDIContainer/), [this](https://simpleinjector.org/blog/2015/12/when-should-you-use-a-container/) and [this](http://kozmic.net/2012/10/23/ioc-container-solves-a-problem-you-might-not-have-but-its-a-nice-problem-to-have/) describe when you should use a container.

That said, constructor injection is just the mere act of *statically declaring the required dependencies of a class* as constructor arguments. Without the use of a container, this means that 'someone' will still call such constructor explicitly (using plain old code) and pass in its dependencies.

Oposed to tightly coupled code however, we try to prevent 'normal' parts of the application from calling those constructors, because that would again result in tightly coupled code. Instead we move this construction to the entry point of the application, the so called [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/).

Such construction in the entry point might look as follows:

```
public Controller CreateController(Type type)
{
    if (type == typeof(HomeController))
        return new HomeController(
            new UserServices(
                new LoggingUsersRepositoryDecorator(
                    new FileLogger(),
                    new UsersRepository(connectionString))));

    if (type == ...)

    return base.CreateController(type);
}
```

If we were to use a DI container, we would only specify mappings between abstractions and implementations in the container; we won't have to specify the dependencies a class requires. What stays the same however is the location where we 'wire' and 'resolve'. Both when practicing Pure DI or when using a tool, we do this in the *Composition Root*.